# Cannot resolve symbol 'setText' and 'toString'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

While following a tutorial I did the same thing he did which he didn't get any errors. it keeps showing me cannot resolve symbol 'setText' and 'toString' i don't why it shows me these errors. I tried File --> Invalidate Caches/Restart... but it didn't work. Here is my MainActivity.java.

```
package com.example.firstapk;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            TextView textValue = findViewById(R.id.text_value);
            String stringValue = textValue.getText().toString();
            int originalValue = Integer.parseInt(stringValue);
            int newValue = MyWorker.doubleTheValue(originalValue);
            textValue.setText(Integer.toString(newValue));

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Snackbar.make(view, "Changed Value " + originalValue + " to " + newValue, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add activity_main.xml and complete error that you get in logcat?

Comment: Do you have a text_value in your .xml file?

Comment: @EraftYps i already have activity_main.xml, thanks for the reply i have solved this thanks to the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move your `textValue.setText(Integer.toString(newValue));` code inside `onClick()` method it will work

Try this

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            TextView textValue = findViewById(R.id.text_value);
            String stringValue = textValue.getText().toString();
            int originalValue = Integer.parseInt(stringValue);
            int newValue = MyWorker.doubleTheValue(originalValue);
            textValue.setText(Integer.toString(newValue));

                Snackbar.make(view, "Changed Value " + originalValue + " to " + newValue, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
```